# How can I change the comment start character for a language in Sublime Text?

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3

I am trying to override the comment start character in Sublime Text's Python bundle. I copied the relevant file, Miscellaneous.tmPreferences, from the Python bundle supplied with the application to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python`, which I think is supposed to be the location to keep bundle overrides, and edited the `TM_COMMENT_START` key in that file. I have restarted Sublime, as well as cleared its cache and restarted, but when I use the Toggle Comment menu command, it is still using the comment start indicator from the built-in bundle. Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been filed at https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/411.

Here's a workaround: make a symlink at `Packages/Python/Miscellaneous.tmPreferences` that points to `User/Python Miscellaneous.tmPreferences`. Then, you can edit either file, save the change, and restart sublime for it to take effect.

EDIT: The bug has been fixed as of build 3109.